# jquery func not working to highlight 3 continuous max values of the input value from 2 html table cells

Tags: html, jquery

When the user enters the table cell value say for example **65000** in the input textbox named BASIC, matching figure will be highlighted with red and the very next value i.e. **67000** will be highlighted to blue.

How to extend the search to the next table? The next closest value in the other table cell is 67700. The result i.e. **67700** could be shown in the Next Basic textbox.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cb').on('change keyup', function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    $('#le10 tr td, #le11 tr td').filter(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == search) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
        $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
        $(this).parent('#le10 tr').closest('#le11 tr').next().addClass('highlight3');
      } else {
        $(this).parent('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().removeClass('highlight2');
        $(this).parent('#le10 tr').closest('#le11 tr').next().removeClass('highlight3');
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight2 {
  color: blue;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight3 {
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>Basic</td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb" autocomplete="off" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h6>Current Level</h6>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h6>Next Level</h6>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h6>Next Basic</h6>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="le10" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td>56100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>57800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>59500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>61300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>63100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>65000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>67000</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table id="le11" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td>67700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>69700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>71800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>74000</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      Next Basic<input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can highlight elements when looping through the elements list `$('#le10 tr td, #le11 tr td')`. For example, below I used `hightlightCount` for checking whether matched element is found, and highlight successive cells accordingly.

```
    var highlightCount = 0;

    $('#le10 tr td, #le11 tr td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == search) {
            ...
            highlightCount = 2;
        } else if (highlightCount == 2) {
            // next cell of matched element
            ...
            highlightCount--;
        } else if (highlightCount == 1) {
            // next next cell of matched element
            ...
            highlightCount--;
        } else {
            ...
        }
    });
```

I also changed `.filter()` to `.each()` so that it is more readable in this case of looping through all elements.

---

Here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cb').on('change keyup', function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    searchText(search);
  });
});

function searchText(search) {

  // set counter for highlight
  var highlightCount = 0;

  $('#le10 tr td, #le11 tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == search) {
      // found matched element
      // reset Next Basic value
      // hightlight cell and set hightlight counter
      $('#nb').val('');
      $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
      highlightCount = 2;
    } else if (highlightCount == 2) {
      // next cell of matched element
      // hightlight cell and decrease hightlight counter
      $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight2');
      highlightCount--;
    } else if (highlightCount == 1) {
      // next next cell of matched element
      // set Next Basic to this element value
      // hightlight cell and decrease hightlight counter
      $('#nb').val($(this).text());
      $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight3');
      highlightCount--;
    } else {
      // remove hightlight for other cells
      $(this).parent('tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2 highlight3');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight2 {
  color: blue;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight3 {
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>Basic</td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb" autocomplete="off" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h6>Current Level</h6>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h6>Next Level</h6>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h6>Next Basic</h6>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="le10" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td>56100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>57800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>59500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>61300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>63100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>65000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>67000</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table id="le11" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td>67700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>69700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>71800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>74000</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      Next Basic<input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: dear charmian the above solution is helpful but when the table id le10 is having more cells like <tr><td>69000</td></tr>
     <tr><td>71100</td></tr>
     <tr><td>73200</td></tr>
     <tr><td>75400</td></tr>
     <tr><td>77700</td></tr> the next highlighted value is showing in the same table cell. Only two values to be highlighted in the table id le10 and then should highlight the next value in table id11. please look into it

Comment: @shankar_sb if you are finding the nearest cell by its value specifically in a different table, it will be quite a different situation. I found some related information here, which you may use to highlight nearest cell in a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244008/find-the-closest-number-in-a-table-to-a-specific-number

Comment: I referred the link.  Here I need only two consecutive cell values in the first table (65000, 67000) to be highlighted and then the third value to be highlighted in other table i.e. 67700 though the previous table is having more cell values after 67000.    In your earlier reference, if at all further values are there after 67000 in the first table, they are getting highlighted continuously. kindly fix the issue pls

Comment: @shankar_sb This will be quite different from the current question and answer, you will need another function to search and mark the "third closest value" in `#le11`, after you found the cells in `#le10`, here "third closest value" means closest value to the cell value next to matched cell I guess? maybe you can refer to the link above for how to search for closest value, and I will suggest to put it as another question.