# jquery function to identify an input value upto 3 levels in two html table cell values and set the max value in the input textbox

Tags: html, jquery

1. there is an input textbox with the name Basic (id=cb) and two html table cell values with ids le10 and le11. I have to check the input value upto 3 consecutive levels (2 values from 1st table and 3rd one from 2nd table).
2. say for eg. if the input value is 69000, the two cell values of table id le10 i.e. 69000 and 71100 to be highlighted (its working with the jquery function)
3. The 3rd value is to be set in the table id le11.  The very next higher value to the 71100 is 71800 in the 2nd table i.e. id le11.  This 71800 to be shown in the input box id= nb.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <style>
    .highlight
    {
    color:red;
    background-color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
    .highlight2 {
      color: blue;
      background-color: yellow;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .highlight3 {
      color: green;
      background-color: yellow;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                     <table width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Basic</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb"  autocomplete="off"/></td>
                        </tr>

    <tr><td>after one increment</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="aftinc" id="aftinc"  autocomplete="off"/></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <td><h6>Current Level</h6></td>
                <td><h6>Promotion Level</h6></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                <table id="le10" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        
                        <tr><td>56100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>57800</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>59500</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>61300</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>63100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>65000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>67000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>69000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>71100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>73200</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>75400</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>77700</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                
                
                <td>
                    <table  id="le11" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
                        
                        <tr><td>67700</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>69700</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>71800</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>74000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>76200</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>78500</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>80900</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>83300</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>85800</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>88400</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>91100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>93800</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            
            
                <td>
                    Next Basic</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb"  autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--match and highlight the Current basic textbox value with the level table-->
    
       <script>
    $(function () {
      $('#cb').on('change keyup', function() {
        var search = $(this).val();
        $('table#le10 tr td').filter(function() {
            if($(this).text() == search){
              $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
             $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
                var aftinc = $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().text();
              $('#aftinc').val(aftinc);
            }else{
              $(this).parent('tr').removeClass('highlight');
              $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().removeClass('highlight2');
            }
        })
      });
    });
    
    
    //for extending the search to the 2nd table
   $(function () {
  $('#aftinc').on('input', function() {
    var search2 = $(this).val();
    $('table#le11b tr td').filter(function() {
        if($(this).text() == search2){
           $(this).closest('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
        }else{
          $(this).closest('tr').next().removeClass('highlight2');
        }
    })
  });
});

    </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent('tr').closest('tr')` (this==td) is the same as `$(this).parent('tr')` - closest looks at the *current element(s)* first- so if you're already on a tr, then it will select that tr, eg: `tr1.closest("tr") == tr1`

Comment: @freedomn-m Did not understand Since I am a beginner.  Kindly give with an example if possible pls

Comment: Read this: https://api.jquery.com/closest/ *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing **the element itself** and [then] traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

Comment: Here's an example.   `var tr = $("td#id1").closest("tr");  var tr2 = tr1.closest("tr");`  tr1===tr2.

Comment: @freedomn-m for my better understanding, can you fix the problem in the existing jquery function pls

Comment: @freedomn-m I added a input textbox with an id aftinc and var aftinc = $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().text(); $('#aftinc').val(aftinc);  after fetching the 2nd consecutive number of the 1st table in the input box, i added a function $(function () {
  $('#aftinc').on('input', function() { var search2 = $(this).val(); $('table#le11 tr td').filter(function() {if($(this).text() == search2){$(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');}else{
          $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().removeClass('highlight2');
        }
    })
  });
}); but not working

Comment: Likely because `$(this).parent('tr').closest('tr')` is the same as `$(this).parent('tr')` so it never gets to your outer `tr`.

Comment: Yah I understood now, I changed to $(this).closest('tr').next().addClass('highlight2'); is working fine only when I type the input textbox id(aftinc), if this inputbox auto change with jquery function its not working.  To my understand, I need to change here : $('#aftinc').on('input', function(), What event suits here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to the answer, what you left to do is to find the next higher value in table `#le11`. To start the search for next higher value, You can simply put the code after searching first two values.
I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68244533/19664304) to get the next higher value as below:

1. push values from table `#le11` to an array
2. if there is second value `aftinc`, find the next higher value of `aftinc` by `Math.reduce`
3. if there is third value found, search and highlight the corresponding cell

I have also make some minor changes to the code, like

- change `$(this).parent('tr').closest('tr')` to `$(this).parent('tr')`, as mentioned in the comments they output the same result
- clear all highlight classes before doing another search, instead of clear it while searching

You can try the code here:

```js
$(function () {

        // get values from table le11 for comparison
        let tableValues = [];
        $('#le11 tr td').each(function () {
            tableValues.push(this.innerHTML)
        });

        $('#cb').on('change keyup', function () {
            var search = $(this).val();

            // clear classes and init values
            $('#le10 tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
            $('#le11 tr').removeClass('highlight3');
            $('#nb').val('');
             
            // find values in #le10
            var aftinc = 0;
            $('#le10 tr td').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() == search) {
                    $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
                    $(this).parent('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
                    aftinc = $(this).parent('tr').next().text();
                    $('#aftinc').val(aftinc);
                }
            });

            // if values found, find next higher value in #le11
            if (aftinc > 0) {
                const closest = tableValues.reduce((prev, curr) => {
                    return Math.abs(curr - aftinc) < Math.abs(prev - aftinc) && (curr - aftinc) > 0 ? curr : prev;
                });

                // check value found
                if (closest - aftinc > 0) {
                    $('#le11 tr td').each(function () {
                        if (this.innerHTML === closest) {
                            // highlight the next higher value
                            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight3');
                        }
                    });
                    $('#nb').val(closest);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.highlight
    {
    color:red;
    background-color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
    .highlight2 {
      color: blue;
      background-color: yellow;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .highlight3 {
      color: green;
      background-color: yellow;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                     <table width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Basic</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb"  autocomplete="off"/></td>
                        </tr>

    <tr><td>after one increment</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="aftinc" id="aftinc"  autocomplete="off"/></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <td><h6>Current Level</h6></td>
                <td><h6>Promotion Level</h6></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                <table id="le10" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        
                        <tr><td>56100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>57800</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>59500</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>61300</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>63100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>65000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>67000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>69000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>71100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>73200</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>75400</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>77700</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                
                
                <td>
                    <table  id="le11" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
                        
                        <tr><td>67700</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>69700</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>71800</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>74000</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>76200</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>78500</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>80900</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>83300</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>85800</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>88400</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>91100</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>93800</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            
            
                <td>
                    Next Basic</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb"  autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: code is working fine but when I placed multiple tables i.e. more than 5 pairs, at $('#nb').val(closest); I am facing issue. How to fix this. In fact, $('#nb').val(closest); not working. In my understanding,  $('#nb').val(closest); => this line of code is executing twice in a loop and hence is not showing result in the input textbox (id: nb)when  with multiple pairs of tables.

Comment: I learnt that const variable can be used for a single time and hence i changed const closest1 = tableValues.reduce((prev, curr) => {.....     const closest2 = tableValues.reduce((prev, curr) => { ... so on...  but the last function only returning the value in inputbox (#nb) remaining all returning nothing.

Comment: @shankar_sb I am not sure if I understand you correctly, if you want to reuse closest inside a loop, you can define closest as var instead of constant. More information is needed to understand your problem, maybe you can open a new question for it.